# Merging cells from muliple rows and columns

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

How can I merge 5 cells from 3 rows (shaping a cross or U) in Excel2010? 
Everything I tried will merge a block of 9 cells together. How can I get around this?

Comment: Are you needing this for display purposes only, or do you need it done this way to make formulas work? This seems like a very odd thing to need in a spreadsheet.

Comment: It is for display purpose but the merged cells has to have merge charactrestic for coloring, boardering, data entering.

Comment: You cant break up a row/column merge....best you can do is a U shape with 2 columns have specified rows merged and then a row with a specified number of columns to complete the U.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible to use cell merging to create shapes in that way, but if you are using it for display purposes, you can accomplish that in one of two ways:

1. You can Overlay an Autoshape, using the Autoshapes toolbar. [Instructions](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-insert-shapes-in-an-excel-2010-worksheet.html)
2. You can use Conditional formatting on the needed cells to apply coloring and data for that shape. That way, even though the cells are still considered separate cells, the visual effect will still be accomplished. [Instructions](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-apply-conditional-formatting-in-excel-2010.html)

Comment: No problem. Please upvote and accept my answer then so I can get credit.